# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string using connect of react-redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

Supposedly, I've got a small problem, but can't tackle it.
I've got a small React-Native app, one screen only.

Redux is used as a store. It's being built via Expo. While using connect of react-redux, I've got the following error: 
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `Home`.

The app works if the component rendered by Home component isn't wrapped by connect().

Attach some code below.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './src/pages/Home';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './src/stores/store';

const { store } = configureStore();

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
},
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    }
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import SwitchEventTypes from "../components/SwitchEventTypes";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SwitchEventTypes />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

SwitchEventTypes.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { updateEventType } from '../actions/actions';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateEventType: (newEventType) => {
            dispatch(updateEventType(newEventType));
        }
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        eventType: state.filter.eventType,
    };
};

class SwitchEventTypes extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isSwitchEventTypeOn: true
        }

        this.handleEventTypeChange = this.handleEventTypeChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleEventTypeChange(newEventType) {
        this.props.updateEventType(newEventType);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.switchTypesContainer}>
                {this.props.eventType === 'active' ? <Text>123</Text> : 
                  <Text>456</Text>
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SwitchEventTypes);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const middleware = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const composedEnhancers = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
)

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancers);
  return { store };
};
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "expo-react-native-shadow": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-svg-uri": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.32.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
```

What may be the matter? Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see you have import SwitchEventTypes class in your Home.js file. Did you forget to mention here or ?

Comment: Forgot to mention. Deleted code parts to make it easy to read. This code works if I make 
export default SwitchEventTypes 

instead of 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SwitchEventTypes);
at SwitchEventTypes.js

Comment: Can you update your answer with how you import this SwitchEventTypes class in Home.js?

Comment: import SwitchEventTypes from "../components/SwitchEventTypes";
(updated the code).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapDispatchToProps is returning an object. You also don't need the extra returns as fat arrow functions already have an implicit return. Will make your code a little more readable.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    updateEventType: (newEventType) => dispatch(updateEventType(newEventType));
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    eventType: state.filter.eventType, // might be worth your time to investigate selectors down the road
};
```